# Design database to hold html, jsp, java, javascript, etc code

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, database-design

i want to build a small tool to save useful code snippet in the database. But don't know which kind of datatype should I use to hold all the codes. Is there problem with `special characters`? can I use `String` to hold code? can you please give me some advice? thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**

i am going to make a table like:

-- ID (UUID) -- -- NAME (String) -- -- TYPE (String) -- -- CODE (String) --

to save code. any tips?

**UPDATE**

here are the ideas:

1. use TEXT and set the right charset. I think I'm going to use `UTF-8`.
2. use BLOB to store the codes

I'm not sure, which one is better. And i need a lecture about this.

Comment: Its varchar when it comes to things like sql.  Also as per my answer for varchars of unknown length the datatype is text.  Blob is the unknown length version of varbinary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Id use a `text` datatype since you could be storing data of any length, Also make sure to use a correct character coding so you can represent the symbols you need.

For reference here is the mySQL reference for TEXT / BLOB http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html

Comment: If the language is whitespace-sensitive I wouldn't use text, I'd use blob instead.  For example, if a table contains 'a', an attempt to store 'a ' causes a duplicate-key error in MySQL. This is not true for BLOB columns.

Comment: Hadn't thought of that, but are you sayin you would never use `TEXT` then?  I use it quite a bit and have never had any problems.  I only ever use BLOB when storing images/pdfs etc.

Comment: Actually I agree with you, TEXT would be better for searching the database :).

Comment: Also, the SQL queries on a TEXT column would not need to be complicated like they would need to be for BLOB or CLOB even (you can't include "WHERE" queries, for example, on -LOB types).

Answer (score 1):

If you store the code as BLOB (byte[]) there should be no char set problems

Comment: Using the correct charset on the database would eliminate this issue anyway.  Don't see any point storing something in binary format when it is clearly text (therefore varchar/text) based.

Comment: Agreed.  FYI - You don't have to set the entire database to use one charset, you can set charset on a per-column basis.  For example, in MySQL there are commands to convert between the charset types in columns: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-conversion.html